# Playing local audio files with Flash and/or HTML5

Tags: flash, html, audio, file-io, local-storage

I realize it is possible to play audio with Flash and HTML5 by passing a URL.

**However, is it possible to get a reference to an audio file using a file browser (either with HTML5 or Flash), to then play this local file, again using either Flash or HTML5?**

Of course, this should happen without the interference of a server. Since the file is already on the local system, it does not make sense to route it through a server only to receive the same file again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Potential solution :

[`window.URL.createObjectURL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.URL.createObjectURL) and [`Audio(src)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLAudioElement)

This solution works with creating object urls and the `Image` constructor but I'm not sure how solid the `Audio` constructor support is.

Don't have a browser that supports both of those available but feel free to test them. You'll need to use the [HTML5 File API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/using_files_from_web_applications) to upload the audio file and manipulate it with JavaScript

Comment: I tested your solution: http://jsfiddle.net/AKCYx/. It works great. However, since HTML5 does not play that many codecs (like mp3 in most browsers), I hope the same functionality is available in flash.

Comment: @Tom Safari, Chrome and IE9 support mp3. Screw firefox users ;). HTML5 media isn't ready to be used as a local device. The best you can do is write a firefox addon for an html5 audio mp3 codec and drop Opera mp3 support. Or abuse flash to get past those pesky html5 security barriers ;)

Comment: @Raynow, well, if the same is possible with flash, that'd be an optimal combination.