# Using JavaScript to read files stored on a user's computer

Tags: javascript

I'm building a website which has a music player that can currently play files stored on the server. I'm using soundManager2 to play the files.

What I would like to do is have the player also play files stored on a user's computer, which may not be possible and will probably hit security risks if it is.

This is a bit of the code I use to plays the files:

```
currentTrack = soundManager.createSound({
id: "Track",
url: file_location+".mp3",
});
```

Then soundManager2 does its magic. As the location of the file is a variable, I was hoping that if a user were to specify the location of an mp3 on their computer it could be put into the variable and played in soundManager, in the same way it finds files on our server and plays them. My thinking is that as soundManager uses javascript and flash, or HTML5 it's all client side so there wouldn't be any security issues and it could just be 'streamed' from their computer without any strain on our bandwidth.

How can this be done?

Comment: reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6634243/playing-local-audio-files-with-flash-and-or-html5

Comment: I suspect that for this to work you'd need to have some client-side server solution, that way the JavaScript talks to the server, the server retrieves the file. But...interesting question. (I do, however, hope it's not possible with *just* JavaScript, though...)

Comment: With the new html5 file api, you can drag files into the browser window and read files stored on a user's computer, without having to upload them to a server. http://html5demos.com/file-api

Comment: Hi David, do you have any idea as to whether adobe air would be a client side solution which could work? I know the BBC Iplayer uses it to play videos you download to your computer.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, soundManager will not help you. However, Flash Player 10+ has the FileReference class, which can be used to load an user selected file directly to a SWF, which then can be played by Flash Player. Here is a description and a working example of how to do it: http://www.multimediacollege.be/2011/04/how-to-play-a-local-mp3-file-in-flash/